# Tips on how to create a good structure for answers and questions

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I need to create a web app where people can ask a question and "randomly"  they recieves an answer.

Let me explain better:

i've a pool of answers and i need to intelligently choose one of these and then show this one to people when they did a question.
my first idea was to create a field in DB where categorize answers; then split the questions, search if a word is contained in it and corresponds to any category and pick an answer randomly in the choosen one.

but i think it isn't the best way! any suggestion? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what are you trying to achieve is quite complicated, I will first implement in my bot is tf-idf algorithm

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf

and make it run on several documents so that you can build your weighting factor for each word. you can for example foreach of your categories parse document related so that your factor will be related to a certain argument.

after you built your tables with this value i think you can perform a search and return a result to the user.

so in short:

1. build td-idf tables for each categories
2. parse the question with  td-idf function
3. search the result in youe answer based on the result of step 2

this will give you a base to build your bot.

Comment: i'llt ry this, if i understood it's something like:
termsFrequency * log(totalDocuments / documentWithTerms, 2);

Comment: i will :) just waiting to see if someone else have other ideas.

Comment: sure, but i think this is the starting point for every bot basically :D